# Is it necessary to overload placement new operator, when we overload new operator?

Tags: c++

I have below piece of code

```
class Test 
{
public:
    Test(){}
    Test(int i) {}

  void* operator new (size_t size)
  {
      void *p = malloc(size);
      return p;
  }
  //void* operator new (size_t size, Test *p)
  //{
     // return p;
  //}
};

int main() { 
   Test *p = new Test;
   int i = 10;
   new(p) Test(i);
}
```

Above piece of code does not compile in visual studio, unless i uncomment out the overloaded placement new operator function.
If i comment out normal overloaded new, in that case also it works fine.
Is overloading of placement new mandatory when overloading normal new operator(If placement new need to be used for that class)

Placement delete related code is not shown here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually no, since it's not often used. But it might be necessary, since when you overload `operator new` in a class, it hides all overloads of the global `::operator new`.

So, if you want to use placement new on objects of that class, do; otherwise don't. Same goes for `nothrow` new.

If you've just changed the allocation scheme, and you're surprised that someone somewhere is using placement new behind your back, that might be something to investigate before applying this band-aid.

If the class is used inside standard library containers, not directly with `new`, the custom allocation scheme should be defined by an Allocator class, not an overload. The default allocator `std::allocator` does not respect member `operator new` overloads, but bypasses them. See below.

---

**Disclaimer**: class-scope `operator new` overloads are mainly useful for debugging, and even then it's tricky to get reliably meaningful semantics. Beware:

- You need to also overload `operator delete`. (Not done in the example in this question.)
- Overloads will be bypassed by the qualified syntax `::new T`. You cannot prevent such bypassing. This is the way that `std::allocator<T>` allocates things. You can specialize `std::allocator` for your types, but that's some way into the rabbit-hole already.
- For each `::operator new` overload introduced by any library, including the canonical placement new from `<new>`, you will have to consider whether it applies to your class and decide whether to add an overload, or otherwise contend with the failure of unqualified `new` expressions.
- For each `::operator new` you adopt into your class, you must supply the corresponding member placement `operator delete` with correct semantics. This is called in case the constructor exits by exception. Failing to have it would result in a memory leak only under very specific circumstances, in a possibly resource-constrained pool.

In summary, member `operator new` is the antithesis of defensive coding.

Comment: Actually it is a good idea to implement placement and nothrow `new` whenever you implement custom `new` for this very reason. You could break existing code by failing to provide the six versions of new and delete (don't forget array forms).

Comment: placement `new` isn't often used in code, but STL containers frequently use it to separate their memory allocation from their object construction.

Comment: @Philip: That's a red flag then, since `std::allocator` obtains its memory from `::operator new`. In that case, the solution is to implement a custom allocator, not to enable the standard one.

Comment: @Potato: no, that's not the problem. The problem is that if `std::vector<MyClass>` needs a placement `new` to construct a `MyClass`, then `MyClass` had better provide one. It doesn't matter where the `vector` got its memory from.

Comment: @Philip: If `vector` is getting its memory from the wrong place, that's a bug. Implementing a custom allocator will also likely require placement new (to the letter of the law, anyway), so it will likely go back in one way or another. Maybe I shouldn't jump to conclusions, but it's definitely an issue.

Comment: @Potato: you haven't demonstrated what is wrong about the place `vector` gets its memory from.

Comment: Sorry but I have to downvote this. Unless `Test` is some private implementation detail, and you can control how it is allocated, you should always provide *all* overloads or *none at all*. To do otherwise is to make the class brittle for any client (infinite set that you don't control). See item 52 of Effective C++.

Comment: @TemplateRex Agreed in principle, but the only real solution is "none at all" because the set of global overloads is potentially infinite. Would you be satisfied if I added a stern warning against class-specific `operator new`? I probably didn't say anything just to avoid the controversy associated with saying never to use a specific language feature.

Comment: @PhilipPotter (and maybe this is insightful to TemplateRex too) Note that `::operator new` is still accessible for any class providing its own `operator new`, and it is used by `std::allocator`. In other words, any overload you provide will be bypassed by the standard allocator and there is nothing you can do to prevent the bypass.

Comment: Agreed on the stern warning, overloading `operator new` is tricky enough (alignment, exceptions, etc.). But if you do it, do it right and overload all of them, as well as all versions of `operator delete`. Would like to use a class that overloads `operator+` but not `operator+=`? The key principle for operator overloading is to **do as the ints do**, i.e. to preserve the complete interface.

Comment: @TemplateRex To reiterate, "overload all of them" is fundamentally impossible. Any library can add more overloads, and all overloads go into global scope (not library namespaces). Following "do as the ints do", one would have to avoid class-scope `operator new` entirely.

Comment: At least the usual  `operator new(size_t, void*)` should be provided for `Test` as well. The "using placement new behind your back" is something that a class author should fix before it happens, IMO, simply because you can't control clients not to use it. At the very least, if you don't do that, it should be clearly documented. Even if `std::allocator` bypasses class overloads, it would be unreasonable to expect that other allocators would do the same.

Comment: @TemplateRex It's improper to specify a function corresponding to incorrect semantics. If a class requires that it be allocated in a specific arena, then placement new shouldn't work. I'm not going to argue this further, but we don't live in a perfect world and sometimes you choose the lesser evil.

Answer (score 1):

Placement new operator doesn't exist by default for a class so when you're making a call to `new(p) Test(i);` C++ compiler can't find a definition of the commented function in the above example. If you uncomment the placement operator new for your class, and comment out the "normal" one then the default "normal" new operator will be used and your code will compile.

Answer (score 0):

implementations of std::_Construct use the **global** placement new. So concerns about STL compatability should not be concerns. But the concern about breaking existing code, that may have been written

`new ((void*)p) thing;`

rather than

`::new ((void*)p) thing;`

is certainly a valid point.